# Subtraction of iterators for unordered_set does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, hashset, unordered-set

Trying to find the index of an element in unordered set. Found that subtraction (operator '-') of iterators is one way of doing it.

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    unordered_set<int> comp; 
    vector<int> res;
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.size(); i++)
    {
        //unordered_set<int>::iterator it = comp.find(nums[i]);
        if (comp.find(nums[i])!=comp.end())
        {
            //int pos = distance(comp.begin(), comp.find(nums[i]));
            auto pos = comp.find(nums[i]) - comp.begin();
            res.push_back((int)pos);
            res.push_back(i);
        }
        comp.insert(target-nums[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

But I get compile error on line with auto pos:

```
no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::unordered_set<int>::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<int, true, false>}' and 'std::unordered_set<int>::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<int, true, false>}')
```

Have included iostream, iterator and unordered_set. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: It is not a good idea to rely on a position in **unordered** set in general

Comment: When reading the duplicate `s/map/unordered_set/g`

Comment: @GemTaylor there is `comp.insert` right there

Comment: Apologies...  :-)

Comment: Why do you need to store that position anyway? It does not make sense

Comment: Thank you all. I want to find the index of two numbers in the vector that adds up to a number given.

Comment: So I get that ordered_set or vector would be right to use for getting an index.

Comment: @Nothing_8484 I do not think so, I do not follow how that index related to your task

Comment: @Slava, for the given vector I am storing the compliments (target value -the element value) of each element in the vector into another container(unordered_set in this case, need to change to ?) while iterating over the given vector and checking if element at current index is present in the new container. The current index and the index in the new container is what I am looking for ie the two numbers whose sum would be equal to the target. Hope I am able to explain :D

Answer (score 2):

The iterators for a unordered set is not random access, therefore you have to use `auto index = std::distance(iterator_a, iterator_b);`

However, this operation is O(N), which will result in your algorithm to be O(N^2), therefore I recommend you to use another algorithm to solve your problem.

Comment: O(N^2) is not the only and worst problems. Bigger problem that elements can be reordered.

Comment: Indeed, as the code inserts (thanks) as it searches, any index would be thrown off by something inserted before it.

Comment: @Slava: Indeed, I didn't analyse the algorithm very well :)

Comment: @GemTaylor index can be broken even if you insert after, so OPs code does not make any sense